# Dictionary access in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift, nsdictionary

Consider the following code which gets an array of dictionaries from a plist:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("books", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
let books:Array = dict.objectForKey("Books") as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> //I hate how ugly and specific this is. There has got to be a better way??? Why can't I just say let books:Array = dict.objectForKey("Books")?

let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform((UInt32(books.count))))
let bookData:Dictionary = books[rnd]
```

Now, I'm having trouble accessing individual book dictionaries:

```
let title:String = bookData.objectForKey("title") //[String: AnyObject] does not have a member named 'objectForKey'

let title:String = bookData["title"] // (String, AnyObject) is not convertible to String
```

What is the proper way to find the title of the book?

Comment: Have you tried `let bookData:Dictionary<String,String> = books[rnd]`? Then your second accessor *should* work. (I'm not at a computer to test)

Comment: [Swift version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822771/1634890)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the new syntactic sugars for Arrays and Dictionaries from Beta 3.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("books", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
let books = dict.objectForKey("Books")! as [[String:AnyObject]]
```

You can access `bookData` as is, automatic type inference should work...

```
let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform((UInt32(books.count))))
let bookData = books[rnd]
```

Put an explicit type for each item in the book dictionary, since we have defined it as `AnyObject`.

```
let title = bookData["title"]! as String
let numPages = bookData["pages"]! as Int
```

**Late edit**

- With the nil coalescing operator `??` you can check for nil values and provide an alternate value like so:

  ```
  let title = (bookData["title"] as? String) ?? "untitled"
  let numPages = (bookData["pages"] as? Int) ?? -1
  ```

Comment: I still get `(String, AnyObject) is not convertible to String` on the line `let title = bookData["title"]! as String
`

Comment: Have you looked what is inside "title"? Is its value also an object?

Comment: Sorry, the error went away. Beta3 is still really buggy for me. I'll mark this as correct. One more question though - why the "!" after bookData["title"]?

Comment: To say that the optional definitely has a value. I think it's called *forced unwrapping* or something.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift:**

If using `Dictionary`:

```
if let bookData = bookData{
   if let keyUnwrapped = bookData["title"]{
      title = keyUnwrapped.string
   }
}
```